# Drawing an irregular shape for hypothesis space representation

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there any way to reproduce the picture below with tikz?
I am relatively unfamiliar with tikz and failed to reproduce anything that looks at least partly like the following representation.

[image]

This is were I've got until now:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut,closed=true]
        \draw (-3.5,0.5) .. (-3,2.5) .. (-1,3.5).. (1.5,3).. (4,3.5);
        \draw (-1,1.5) ellipse (57pt and 33pt);
        \draw [fill=black] (-0.5,1.5) circle (1.5pt);
        \draw[color=black] (-0.5,1.2) node {$f$};
        \draw [fill=gray] (0,1.2) circle (1.5pt);
        \draw[color=gray] (0,0.9) node {$h_1$};
        \draw [fill=gray] (-1.2,2) circle (1.5pt);
        \draw[color=gray] (-1.2,2.3) node {$h_2$};
        \draw [fill=gray] (-1,1.35) circle (1.5pt);
        \draw[color=gray] (-1.3,1.35) node {$h_3$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The two most challenging tasks are to reproduce this irregular shape in the same form and to draw these irregular arrows.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Please post a **working** example, not one that doesn't compile.

Comment: I've updated it.

Comment: Side-note: Please consider drawing a well defined shape if possible to make your point. Irregular shapes are not necessarily intuitive or more informative. Instead you can define a particular shape that has a certain difficult-to-handle kink and so on and work your way out on that one to make your point crystal clear.